# rails 3 merge multiple queries from different tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, merge

i have the following queries in my controller. Is there any way that i can merge them into one?

```
@record_videos = RecordVideo.where("recommand = ?",true).limit(8)
@musics=Music.limit(13)
@new_topics=Topic.limit(5).order("created_at desc")
```

Comment: is there any good reason why would you want to merge them into one line, you'll have a hell of a long mysql code if you'll merge it.

Comment: thanks for your comments. There are five separate query in one page, i thought it would be faster if i use one query instead of five. I guess i was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot combine multiple queries that return different classes of object. Well, you *could*, theoretically, if you wrote your own query SQL and used a few `UNION`s, but Rails would likely have no idea what to do with the resulting data. I can't, offhand, think of a use-case where this would be a good idea.

Now, you can easily combine the results of the queries after the fact in your Ruby code - if, for instance, you wanted to sort them all together, you could do this:

```
@all_items = [@record_videos.all, @musics.all, @new_topics.all].flatten.sort_by{ |thing|   thing.created_at}
```

Comment: thanks for your comments. There are five separate query in one page, i thought it would be faster if i use one query instead of five. I guess i was wrong.

Comment: @user1611237 You are not wrong, each of those calls is calling the database.  This is a hack, it works but it's not the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way, I dare say the correct way to merge queries is by using the Active Record Method [merge](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/SpawnMethods/merge)

```rb
RecordVideo.where("recommand = ?",true).limit(8).merge(
  Music.limit(13).merge(
    Topic.limit(5).order("created_at desc")
  )
)
```

Where this query would look to grab all of those conditions.  Keep in mind this does not merge on "OR", these are merged with "AND".